# Open Angular CDK Menu programatically

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

Some of the options in the menu should open a new one in it's place. This is my component ATM:

```
<app-btn-filters
  #dimensionsBtn
  [cdkMenuTriggerFor]="dimensionsMenu">
  Filters
 </app-btn-filters>

<ng-template #dimensionsMenu>
  <div cdkMenu>
      <button
        *ngFor="let dim of group"
        (cdkMenuItemTriggered)="handleDimensionSelection(dim.value)"
        cdkMenuItemRadio>
        {{ dim.display }}
      </button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Is there a way to programatically open a new menu `#selectionMenu` on `handleDimensionSelection()`?

The closest I got was:

```
<app-btn-filters
  #dimensionsBtn
  [cdkMenuTriggerFor]="someState ? dimensionsMenu : selectionMenu">
  Filters
 </app-btn-filters>

<ng-template #dimensionsMenu>
  ...
</ng-template>


<ng-template #selectionMenu>
  ...
</ng-template>
```

but I need it to be open as soon as the user selects said option.

[Here's a working snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-41looq?file=src%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.ts)

In the [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/menu/api#CdkMenuTrigger) there is an "open()" method but I have no clue how to access it.

Answer (score 2):

In your Typescript class, you can get a reference to the trigger object with this:

```
@ViewChild(CdkMenuTrigger) trigger: CdkMenuTrigger;
```

Then later in the class, to open the menu, call:

```
this.trigger.open();
```